# What can we tell about the different aliens in "No One Will Save You"?

Tags: no-one-will-save-you

There seem to be three alien species in *No One Will Save You*.  Are they supposed to be different, or are they just variants (perhaps by developmental stage or type – like in hive species) of the same?

The first alien we see is the most conventionally humanoid, but the second one (that Brynn kills) seems more .. *canine*?  Unlike the more humanoid aliens it doesn't appear to have telekinetic powers, and its behavior has a more aggressive/vicious quality. Have the aliens brought pets and let them roam free to terrorize people or is this supposed to be the same type as the first?

The giant third type (and the third that Brynn kills) seems to serve as an air traffic controller, but when it decides to go after Brynn its behavior also has an unhinged aggression like the canine's, and it also displays no telekinesis.

(Typically production teams put a lot of thought into these sorts of designs and have some concept of back story, so there is likely to be a definitive answer with respect to the *intent* of the movie.)

Comment: This either seems to be quite vague "what's the story with those?" and/or potentially 2 different questions about 2 different type of alien.

Comment: @iandotkelly - This seems pretty answerable in its current form. Are all of the aliens  part of the same species or are some of them entirely different? Like the difference between a human safari hunting party that comprises people from different continents versus one that contains some humans *and an elephant*

Comment: Interesting that the daddy long legs ones weird shape movements were not scripted and they just kind of liked what came out of the mocap session and went with it.

Comment: Duffield: "they all have names. There’s a whole religion. I mean, I know how they breed. I went all deep into it; it was really fun."

Comment: Apparently the humanoid ones like music too, as they try to sing her favorite record (that she played earlier) back to her.

Comment: I've watched and read several interviews with the director, Brian Duffield, but unfortunately, he doesn't elaborate on the different types of aliens.